Book in which people with magic abilities have to wear bracelets that stop their powers; the larger the bracelet, the stronger the power
I remember reading this strange book around 2018. There was a sequel, but I never read it.
The story was set in a modern city where, when people have magic abilities, they have to wear these bracelets that stop their powers. The bigger the bracelet, the stronger the power. The main character is a teenage boy who finds out he has powers and is really strong, but makes it look like he’s weaker so that he can still use his abilities. He teams up with this girl who can see through his disguise. His disguise was that he put someone else’s hair on his head and it made him look like that person.
And that’s all I remember, but it’s been bothering me for a while, because I can’t figure out what this book is called.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, was the book set in a medieval world or a modern city?

It was in the modern city I read it probably around 2018 there was a sequel to it also but I never read it
